# HashMap<String, boolean> copy all the keys into HashMap<String, Integer>and initialize values to zero

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

What is the best way ?

Just looping through and putting the key and zero, or is there another more elegant or existing library method. I am also using Google's guava java library if that has any useful functionality ?

Wanted to check if there was anything similar to the copy method for lists, or Map's [putAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method, but just for keys.

Comment: Please, rephrase your question, I couldn't understand it.

Comment: I would just loop through the keys, it would only take three lines of code. If you want it shorter you could write a method to do it.

Comment: Note that if you use a Multiset instead of a Map you don't have to initialize all the keys to zero.  The first time you add any number of occurrences of a new key it will initialize it for you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't think there's much need for anything fancy here:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = ...;
Map<String, Integer> newMap = Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(map.size());
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
  newMap.put(key, 0);
}
```

If you do want something fancy with Guava, there is this option:

```
Map<String, Integer> newMap = Maps.newHashMap(
    Maps.transformValues(map, Functions.constant(0)));

// 1-liner with static imports!
Map<String, Integer> newMap = newHashMap(transformValues(map, constant(0)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Looping is pretty easy (and not inelegant). Iterate over the keys of the original `Map` and put it in them in the new copy with a value of zero.

```
Set<String> keys = original.keySet();
Map<String, Integer> copy = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String key : keys) {
    copy.put(key, 0);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using `new Integer(0)` is very wasteful of the heap. Consider using 0 and letting the autoboxing work, or if you detest autoboxing, use `Integer.valueOf(0)`.

Comment: I was just trying to give a simple answer.  And autoboxing is the same as new Integer(0), is it not?  Yes, Integer.valueOf(0) would use less memory.

Comment: Nope, it does `Integer.valueOf(0)` (which uses cached boxed values for numbers between -128 and 127).

Answer (score 1):

```
final Integer ZERO = 0;

for(String s : input.keySet()){
   output.put(s, ZERO);
}
```

Comment: Why create a constant named ZERO? If it doesn't add meaning to the value, why not use 0?

Comment: @Isac: Not sure but wont Integer.valueOf(0) be evaluated for every loop ?

Comment: @Isac: Pretty sure that'd be to avoid boxing every iteration, which may be slightly better in terms of performance. I don't feel like it's worth the reduced clarity though.

Comment: Yes, but so? It gets inlined by the JIT compiler into the cached 0 value every time.