# How to use hashmap with multiple data types for request params?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to use `putBoolean` with `put`? I can't figure out how to have a hashmap that can handle string and boolean request params at the same time.

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

params.put("name", "Name here");
params.put("gender", "Female");
params.putBoolean("isStudent", true); //this is not working...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because `true` is not a String. You can change `String` to `Object` as a value.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156306/hashmapstring-boolean-copy-all-the-keys-into-hashmapstring-integerand-init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156306/hashmapstring-boolean-copy-all-the-keys-into-hashmapstring-integerand-init)

Comment: Though you can do as @MarounMaroun says, there are high changes you will get runtime exception if you don't handle correctly. Why do you want to this?

Comment: accept answer if code will help you

Comment: Err, if you have a `Map<String, String>`, you can't put booleans or `Booleans` into it, trivially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `putBoolean()` method in HashMap.
Try this

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

params.put("name", "Name here");
params.put("gender", "Female");
params.put("isStudent", true);
```

when you get that key use this code.

```
Boolean isStudent = (Boolean)params.get("isStudent");
```

Comment: There is no `putBoolean ` in hashmap dear. `params.putBoolean("isStudent", true);` // will not work

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, perhaps I got confused with this http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util.prefs/PreferencesputBooleanStringkeybooleanvalue.htm :)

Answer (score 6):

You can can store a object format like this

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

params.put("name", "Name here");
params.put("gender", "Female");
params.put("isStudent", true);
```

While getting data you can typecast object into literals. Like

```
// In case of String 
String name=(String)param.get("name");
// In case of Boolean 
Boolean isStudent=(Boolean)param.get("isStudent");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    params.put("name", "Name here");
    params.put("gender", "Female");
    params.put("isStudent", true);

    for (String s : params.keySet()) {
        Object obj = params.get(s);
        if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
            //do something
        }
        else if (obj instanceof String) {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type "Object", but only if you really need it. When you use Object type, you can put any value to your map, and it may occur errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make your map value as Object

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

params.put("name", "Name here");
params.put("gender", "Female");
params.putBoolean("isStudent", true);
```